# pandoc to produce pdf with latex, "paper" document class: missing affiliation and date

Tags: pdf, latex, pandoc

I am new to `pandoc` *and* `latex`. I cannot get to have the author affiliation to be part of the final pdf I produce using document class `paper`.

Let's assume I have the following `source.md` file:

```
---
title: my super document
subtitle: blablabla
author:
  - me
  - my friend
  - my other friend
institute: alien space agency
date: <#today>
header-includes:
  - \\usepackage{endnotes}
abstract: |
  This document describes a super research project.
---
start of the writing blablabla...
```

`<#today>` is a `gpp` macro that translates to `\today` in the tex source.

I use `pandoc` like this:

```
cat source.md | gpp -H --include macros.gpp | pandoc -f markdown --variable documentclass=paper --standalone --smart --atx-headers --from=markdown+yaml_metadata_block -o document.pdf
```

In the produced `document.pdf`, there is no date and no affiliation for authors.
However, if I use document class `article` I have the correct date. But still
no authors institute.

How can I have both date and authors institute with `paper` document class ?

**edit**: more info...

If I produce a tex document here is what I get:

```
\title{my super document}
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{}
\subtitle{blablabla}
\author{me \and my friend \and my other friend}
\providecommand{\institute}[1]{}
\institute{alien space agency}
\date{\today}
```

Which looks ok to me. But there are only authors (without institute) and no date in the final document. I assume it is because of `paper` document class, changing to `article` shows the date but no institute...

My pandoc version is **1.19.2.1**

Comment: make sure you use the most recent pandoc version, then `pandoc -D latex` to see which variables you can use or see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-by-pandoc

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see I can use `institute`, it is written in the output of `pandoc -D latex` ; I think my problem is in the document class I am using: `paper`. I like `paper` style but... I am not sure what's wrong in anyways. The same goes for the date.

Comment: yeah, sure has to do with the latex document class... try pandoc 2.0 and maybe ask on pandoc-discuss (at least the manual should be updated to specify what document classes that variable works with...)

Comment: you can also try debugging the generated latex by writing it to a file, then run `pdflatex` directly on it. or switch to `context` (which is like a cleaner LaTeX) or `wkhtmltopdf` (which uses HTML/CSS) for PDF generation (depending on your needs), see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf